# Pegar arquivo sem saber a extensão dele

Tags: php

Como faço para pegar uma imagem mesmo sem saber a extensão dela? por exemplo:

Nome da imagem é **lua**, mas não sei a extensão e quando tento usar comandos php
da erro e diz que não encontrou o arquivo

Como posso pegar um arquivo só pelo nome sem saber a extensão?

Comment: o que você quer dizer com pegar?

Comment: @durtto Importar do meu próprio servidor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tente usar a função glob

```
foreach (glob("lua.*") as $archive) {
    // faça sua mágica aqui
}
```

Ou também pode limitar as extensões

```
glob("lua.{jpg,png}")
```

Referencia: 
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php

Comment: Excente solução, pode colocar o link dos docs desse metodo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php

Comment: Opa, bem lembrado. Acabei me esquecendo de colocar a referencia.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode procurar todos os arquivos de um diretório usando a função **scandir**, e depois comparando o nome usando a função **pathinfo**, usando o parâmetro **PATHINFO_FILENAME**. Fique à vontade para alterar esse script para as suas necessidades.

```
<?php
$dir = '/tmp';
$dirFiles = scandir($dir);
$search = 'lua';

foreach($dirFiles as $file) {
    if (is_file($dir.'/'.$file) AND pathinfo($dir.'/'.$file, PATHINFO_FILENAME) == $search) {
        // aqui você pode fazer o que quiser
        echo "Arquivo encontrado: ".$dir.'/'.$file;
    }
}
?>
```

Seguem os links da documentação do php para as funções usadas:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.scandir.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php